# Android- Checking Input Entered In EditText Field

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development and was trying to make a betting game. 
In my app there's a field where user is required to enter his bet, now the bet should satisfy the following conditions:
-Minimum value of bet is 5
-Bet should be less than player's current point.

Now don't want the game(app) to proceed further untill the player enters a Valid bet.

How can I achiecve this? I'm struck on this problem since past 2 days.

Comment: You need to add a textwatcher (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and check the value any time the text is changed

Comment: Put one text watcher and implement your logics in onTextChanged() method.

Answer (score 0):

it is not about simple if statements ?

```
if(editTextbetamount>5 && editTextbetamount<usersCurrentPoint){

}else{
//toasting something for example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a textChange listenerto your editText

```
editTextView.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
               // Do your logic here
              if(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()) >= 5 && playersCurrentPoint >= Integer.parseInt(s.toString){
                  // proceed
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        };
```